# Is this resonable jump to label compile error with initialization of constexpr variables

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

I found crossing initialization of `constexpr` variables still counts a compile-time error when jump across it, in C++11 (At least in my compile environment)

Consider the following code:

```
t foo()
{
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int T = foo();
    if (T == 0)
        goto JumpLabel;

    constexpr int lowBound = 3;
    constexpr int upBound = 10;

    if (T >= lowBound && T <= upBound)
        return 1;

JumpLabel:
    return 0;;
}
```

The `goto` statement triggers a compile-time error in C++11.  Is this error reasonable?  It's just a cross of `constexpr` variables, which initialize nothing!   I only have C++11 compiler.  Any one can tell me, is it still an error in higher standard, for example, C++14, C++17?

=== UPDATE ===

another program not using `goto` with same problem:

```
int bar()
{
    return 3;
}

int foo()
{
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int T = foo();
    int U = bar();

    switch (T) {
    case 0:
        constexpr int lowBound = 3;
        constexpr int upBound = 10;

        if (U >= lowBound && U <= upBound)
            return 1;

    default:
        T = -1;
    }

    return T;
}
```

Comment: *"It's just a cross of constexpr variables, which initialize nothing!"* - How did you figure that?

Comment: It's a simple constexpr of integer type.  It should be easy enough to be resolved in compile time.

Comment: I doubt you'd find a lot of support in the standards committee to make `goto` easier to use. It's rarely the right tool for the job. In your case, you should just return.

Comment: goto isn't used correctly here you should just return instead of jumping to a return

Comment: It's just an easy example to show the problem.  I can just replace `goto` to other flow control statements.

Comment: *" It should be easy enough to be resolved in compile time"* - Doesn't mean tomorrow someone won't add a call to a function that takes the address of that variable. Or that they won't do it after the label. This prohibition is to future proof your code as well. And seeing as there's virtually no reason to use goto in C++. who cares if it's "too restrictive"?

Comment: I'd love to see how you can replace goto here and still get the same error. You can't. Not with any other control flow statement other than a switch (which is a dolled up goto anyway).

Comment: "Is this reasonable jump" - you used goto, while some think that it has its place, in 20 years I've not needed to use it.  For that reason I'd argue that it's not a "reasonable" jump.  That said, however much I think it shouldn't be, it IS part of the language, and for that I think this makes it a good question.

Comment: @BaummitAugen until they get rid of that feature, it's still a feature in the language - And while I don't disagree with anything you say in your comment, I also think it's off topic as it's clearly just a minimal example.

Comment: OK. I admit that other flow control statements may solve the problem.  It's essentially the same as using a curly parenthesis to quote those codes between `goto` and the label, since all other flow control statement has block-style (curly parenthesis) syntax.    But it's off topic.   The argument for why `goto` should or should not be used, is another topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any one can tell me, is it still an error in higher standard, for example, C++14, C++17?

[Yes, it apparently still is](https://godbolt.org/g/md7Gj7).

You can [introduce a scope](https://godbolt.org/g/ckCQhU) to fix your issue, which also eliminates any concerns regarding initialization, lifetimes etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can't cross *any* initialization with a `goto` (or a jump inside a `switch` construct), no matter whether it is `const`, `constexpr` or neither.
With GCC you can [compile your code using `-fpermissive`](https://godbolt.org/g/r8E1Wc), but if you *really* think you need the `goto`, either put variable initializations inside a local scope (also possible after a `switch` label):

```
    if (T == 0)
        goto JumpLabel;
    {
        constexpr int lowBound = 3;
        constexpr int upBound = 10;

        if (T >= lowBound && T <= upBound)
            return 1;
    }
JumpLabel:
    return 0;
```

Or initialize them before the jump (or outside the `switch`)

```
constexpr int lowBound = 3;
constexpr int upBound = 10;

switch (T) {
case 0:
    if (U >= lowBound && U <= upBound)
        return 1;
default:
    T = -1;
}
```

I don't know the corresponding section of the standard, but I guess the reason this is not allowed, is because for non-`constexpr` you would get unclear behavior when accessing a variable which was initialized between a `goto` and the label. And allowing it just for `constexpr` does not really make sense (either you can initialize it outside the jump, or inside a local scope).